# Need some guidance on what is a spam

Tags: discussion

When I searched on this topic here I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606499/browser-loads-but-shows-blank) response where the definition of a Spam appeared to be:

...it is not spam when:
1. it's strictly on topic and helpful to OP
2. an answer clearly discloses poster's affiliation with the product
3. it's done sparingly

And then I reviewed a post where I clearly found the subject as off-topic and marked it accordingly as Spam. Later to my surprise, I found that the post has been put on hold as **Off Topic**, the very same reason I marked it as a Spam, but my flag was declined citing no evidence found.

I am referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606499/browser-loads-but-shows-blank) that I reviewed yesterday. I don't intend to get the review fixed, but need experts guidance strictly for my own knowledge and curiosity to help me perform future reviews.

Comment: Just being off-topic doesn't make a post spam. That post isn't promoting anything.

Comment: Sometimes I find garbage questions, which ain't promote anything like recently I saw a test from SO which had chinese characters. How do we classify them?

Comment: @DROY, garbage goes to 'offensive' category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup><sub>**spam guidelines** - content taken from [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/314988)</sub></sup>

### What makes something *spam* and when should I flag it?

A post should be marked as spam **ONLY** when it contains an [unsolicited advertisement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29).

It should **NOT** be marked as spam when:

- The answer contains no useful information, such as an answer that says "I don't care about your problem". Flag an answer as 'not an answer' instead; if you find a weird non-question, then flag it 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation.
- It contains only gibberish, such as "fsdguejgkfdlk". [Use the 'abuse' flag for these cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/152859), or flag 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation if it requires more detail.([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/has-there-been-an-uptick-in-spam-votes-against-established-questions/56224#56224))

Comment: An offensive flag on "fsdguejgkfdlk" would be declined.

Comment: 'Low quality'  suits for it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey An offensive flag on "fsdguejgkfdlk" should be marked helpful according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035 the reason is that its abuse of the system

Comment: After conferring in the Teacher's Lounge, I withdraw my assertion.  Note that the flag is no longer called an "offensive" flag; it's called "rude or abusive," which kinda means something different.  Note to self: it's still called an Offensive flag in the Moderator Dashboard.