# Edit war: How do I raise a flag without getting declined by moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, rollback-wars

I have observed an edit war on SO. The OP keeps on editing the question by replacing the original (answered) question with junk text, while >2k users are trying to keep the original:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36877430/revisions)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36877861/revisions)

I have raised an abusive flag. A moderator reviewed my flag (2:30 hrs after the flag was raised). As expected, the moderator declined my flag (the question is back with original content at that point of time).

How do I raise my flags in this context? *Abusive* will most likely be declined. (Note: At this period, I have observed that most of the users with moderator privileges are offline.)

How does a moderator review page looks like (for spam & abusive reviews)? Does it include flag weight? Or helpful percentages of the user who raised the flag?

99% of my flags (total 683) are helpful. Only two were declined (including this one). Will there be any difference in the page view while reviewing?

Comment: For clarity: you raised the flag called "rude or abusive", the second one from the top? The one that's for posts that are currently filled with rudeness or personal attacks?

Comment: [Gibberish text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035) will be treated as [abusing the system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320982/need-some-guidance-on-what-is-a-spam/320985#comment333307_320985)

Comment: Yes... and no. That really only works if the gibberish is essentially the only thing that's ever existed. Otherwise, the abuse is not the *obvious gibberish* per se, but the (repeated) editing to that state. I suppose that's a subtler point, though.

Comment: Hmmm.. As mentioned in [my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322511/edit-war-how-do-i-raise-flag-without-getting-declined-by-moderator#comment341332_322512), I flagged it immediately after seeing the junk. Later, observed post being edited multiple times. Now I learnt that I should custom flag with a message to moderator. Otherwise, there is a high probabilty that busy guys gonna decline it.

Comment: When you make an edit to your post, doesn't it get 'shifted' up in the new posts, like it was just posted (in the newest tab)? Maybe the OP is 'vandalizing' his post on purpose so that he gets the visibility. Which is also  bad imo.

Comment: I think the OP is really trying to delete their post rather than "vandalize" it.

Answer (score 64):

I would write what you wrote here:

> OP keeps on editing the question by replacing original( answered) question with junk text, while >2k users trying to keep the original.

That gives the moderator all the information they need to identify and address the problem. The "abusive" flag doesn't - if the post isn't abusive *when they see the flag*, then there's nothing to be done (and the flag looks crazy).

Comment: what if edit war happens after raising the flag ? I didn't mention in my question, but I observed edit war after the flag was raised. Shall I flag another ? custom flag with a text to moderator ?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me...

Comment: On another similar question, [ChrisF wrote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/4174897): _"Therefore you can see that all the cases where a moderator might need to intervene [during an edit war] are already catered for with automatically generated flags, Therefore, you should do nothing."_ Plus, one can get flags declined due to the fact that they were already raised by the system (see [ChrisF's question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987/4174897)). Won't people reading this answer get their flags declined?

Comment: There was no auto-flag in this scenario, @kyll. Folks get in a bind when they want to flag for problems they could just fix; if you can fix, by all means fix... If you can't, if you're just watching someone behaving badly unable to stop it... Then please do flag, and be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if a flag was raised or not since the numbers are kept secret to prevent abuse? In a multiple-self-deface scenario, does that mean I _should_ raise a flag but I may get it declined because the system raised one too? Should I raise a flag before there were two defacements and one rollback? Two rollbacks? Three defacements and three rollbacks..?

Comment: Why are you worried about auto-flags, @kyll? The system can only see that someone's rolling back a lot or making lots of big edits; it can't see what effects these have, but you can. Unless you're flagging *without providing any useful information*, your flags are better than auto flags.

Comment: @Shog9 Because ChrisF [_very explicitly_ said that piling on auto-flags is a good reason to get them declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987/4174897). This means that if someone just flags when they see multiple self-defacements they would get their flag declined with `A flag was already raised by the system`.

Comment: So don't "pile on" then @kyll. Flag when there's a real problem, *and describe the problem*. Yeah, for sure don't go running around flagging every dramatic edit as "possible vandalism" or every heavily-edited post as "edit war"; use your brain to identify problems and your words to describe them. The system can't do those things, you can... If you want to.

Answer (score 32):

Just use

> #### in need of moderator intervention
>
> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

and write why are you flagging the question.

---

Abusive flag acts like spam flag. In most cases it adds a downvote from community, and if there are 5 such flags, deletes the post with replacing its content with a cap. Not sure how it works if set on question with answers.

Comment: 6 flags actually.

Answer (score 7):

Don't raise a flag when an edit war is happening. A flag was already raised automatically!

From [ChrisF's self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4174897):

> #### Per-post flags
>
> - (...)
> - too many edits (auto) - an author edited their post more than a certain number of times

In the question you can read:

> I recently had a flag declined. The moderator said it was the same as an automatically-raised flag, and therefore **I was wasting my flag, my time, and the moderators' time in flagging it again**. However, I didn't know this.

(Emphasis mine)

Finally, in another answer on a similar question, [ChrisF wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/4174897):

> Therefore you can see that all the cases where a moderator might need to intervene are already catered for with automatically generated flags,
>
> Therefore, you should do nothing.
>
> In particular you should move on should a rollback war looks like it's going to start - i.e. the OP has rolled back the rollback. We'll get notifications and deal with it appropriately.

So, overall, if you see defacing going on and it has never been rollbacked then please do the rollback.
If OP persists in defacing and trying to vandalize their post, move along: The mods are coming.

Note that [Brad Larson commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag/306821#comment251268_306821):

> The only thing I'd add is that a custom moderator flag may be warranted if the user defaced their question in an offensive or insulting way.

That would be the only case a moderator flag is warranted, *carefully explaining the situation*. Example:

> This user is defacing their own post multiple times against rollbacks in an offensive way.